# Compare files shows unchanged files TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I am trying to compare two branches on TFS and TFS is showing files which do not have any differences.

I tried taking latest and resolving conflicts but that did not help. I don't know what's the problem.

[image]

[image]

What else can I do to make it go away?

Comment: There'll be whitespace differences - at the beginning of some of the lines. I have yet to find the option to either ignore these or highlight them.

Comment: I think this is just the very poor decision of the Microsoft team (starting VS 2012) to not show an explicit "files identical" message. Instead, they show you the identical files and then you have to figure out that they are identical from the lack of markers on the right scroll! Still frustrating in 2019.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to turn off the option to trim whitespace, which can be found on the Compare Files toolbar:

[image: Compare Files toolbar]

You can also toggle `Edit -> Advanced -> View Whitespace` to see which ones are spaces vs. tabs, which on my machine has 3 separate keyboard mappings:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>

(You can remap this if you want by going to `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard`.)

Comment: But what can you do to make it not show file in the list? I don't get that option on folder difference screen.

Comment: @FahadMullaji you can't make it not show in the list if there are changes to the file.  Have you verified that there aren't any whitespace differences?